# How to animate view layer shadow with UIViewPropertyAnimator

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation

I know we need to use `CABasicAnimation` to animate shadow, but I don't know how to integrate `UIViewPropertyAnimator` with `CABasicAnimation`.

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: If you can, have a look at Matt Neuburg's book, the one that's indepth into views and UIKit etc. That book covers all the nitty gritty you need to do this sort of thing better than anything I've seen. Having said that... I don't actually know how to do this. Or much else. Short term memory loss impact from being frequently blazed, dazed and

Comment: @Confused I refer to his book as the bible.  I just wish it had more pictures.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
let shadowAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "shadowOpacity")
shadowAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
shadowAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
shadowAnimation.fromValue = 0.3
shadowAnimation.toValue = 0
shadowAnimation.duration = transitionDuration

animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: transitionDuration, dampingRatio: 95, animations: {
    topShadowContainer.layer.add(shadowAnimation, forKey: "shadowOpacity")
}
```

I found the solution.

Comment: you don't have to execute the `CABasicAnimation` inside of a `UIViewPropertyAnimator`. just calling `<view>.layer.add(animation:forKey:)` will do.

Comment: This snippet just executes the animation in the block. You don't have the ability to utilize UIViewPropertyAnimator's pause, reverse, and other methods.

Comment: @Sean Do you know a way that would allow for UIViewPropertyAnimator's pause, reverse, etc functionality?